# Access violation on CompStr(BSTR, BSTR) after getting string?

Tags: c++, com, bstr

I am getting an access violation that I can't figure out when trying to compare to BSTR strings in a c++ function. For whatever reason, the code runs normally most of the time. But on occasion, seemingly randomly, it will throw the exception. This is what I'm doing:

```
BSTR myString; // also tried this with a CComBSTR, same result, but less often it seemed
pSomeObject->GetString(&myString);
if (!CompStr(someOtherString, myString))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

SomeObject::GetString is:

```
STDMETHODIMP SomeObject::GetString(BSTR* outStr)
{
  if (!outStr) return E_POINTER;

  *outStr = ::SysAllocString(m_memberString);

  return S_OK;
}
```

I'm getting the access violation in CompStr which is:

```
inline bool CompStr(BSTR str1, BSTR str2)
{
  UINT len1 = ::SysStringLen(str1);
  UINT len2 = ::SysStringLen(str2);  // this is where I'm getting the access violation

  return CompStr(str1, len1, str2, len2);
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or why it's failing?

Comment: Are you sure both `str1` and `str2` were both allocated with `SysAllocString`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are. I know my string (str2) is being initialized, but I'll dig deeper into the other code paths to see if str1 isn't being initialized somewhere.

Comment: In the debugger inspect the value of `str2`. Also there could have been undefined behavour earlier (e.g. a buffer overflow) and only when you allocate another string does that damage show up.

Comment: @climbak not just "initialized somewhere", it must have specifically been created with `SysAllocString` (or family). BSTR is a length-counted string; if you try passing a null-terminated (non length counted) string then you are in for some trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `myString`, and not checking `GetString()` for an error result.

```
BSTR myString = NULL; // CComBSTR initializes for you
if (SUCCEEDED(pSomeObject->GetString(&myString)))
{
    if (!CompStr(someOtherString, myString))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

```
STDMETHODIMP SomeObject::GetString(BSTR* outStr)
{
    if (!outStr) return E_POINTER;

    *outStr = ::SysAllocString(m_memberString);
    if (!*outStr) return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Also, make sure `someOtherString` is allocated as a `BSTR`, otherwise `SysStringLen()` will not work on it.  I would suggest changing `CompStr()` to use `WCHAR*` and `lstrlenW()` instead. You can pass a `BSTR` to a `WCHAR*`:

```
inline bool CompStr(WCHAR* str1, WCHAR* str2)
{
    UINT len1 = ::lstrlenW(str1);
    UINT len2 = ::lstrlenW(str2);

    return CompStr(str1, len1, str2, len2);
}
```

Comment: I unfortunately am limited to BSTR, but I'll look into the someOtherString and see if it has any paths in other's code where it's not being initialized. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @climbak You don't need to initialize `myString` since you set in `GetString` and failing to check the return value of `SysAllocString` wouldn't cause `SysStringLen` crash because it returns 0 if passed a NULL pointer. However changing your code to use `lstrlenW` or `wcslen` is worth a try to see if it causes your code to behave differently.

Comment: If this does seem to fix the problem then OP must have not allocated `str1` correctly, so that should be fixed otherwise the same sort of problem may just show up in a different piece of code.

Comment: I was getting the string from another function that gets it from various places depending on conditions. One of those was not using SysAllocString and was just returning nothing.